# Is there a way to do ask deploy through jenkins?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins-pipeline, alexa-skills-kit, ask-cli

I want to automate the process of deploying Alexa skill through and want my pipeline to do the following for me:-

1. ask deploy --target lambda if my lambda has been modified
2. ask deploy --target model if my models have been modified.

I know I can put an IF condition either to check **[git log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)** or check **[changeset](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-58441)** in Jenkins and it Will solve my purpose, but since my skill is already in production I don't want to add any risk that by mistake skill gets modified and I will have to send it for re certification again.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution, Thanks to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52764757/how-do-i-revise-a-live-alexa-skill). I was under a misconception that Amazon discards my production version of skill as soon as I deploy new changes to it.It is rather different.

Now this is what I am doing:-

1. I am using ask deploy to deploy my lambda as well as skill.
2. I can send it for re certification whenever I wish and till then develop on my current Dev version.
3. Using Aliases for Prod deployment of lambda and can re-deploy my lambda on default $LATEST version till I don't decide to publish it to PROD.